# Creating a Table from a Grocery CRUD Query Result

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have created a website based on Grocery Crud and it works fine. Imagine if I have a table like below:

id |  name | age

1  |  x    | 12

2  |  y    | 20

3  |  z    | 12

then, I did this query "age=12", the Grocery Crud gives the result:

id |  name | age

1  |  x    | 12

3  |  z    | 12

The question is how can I create a new table from this Grocery CRUD Query Result? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the where function, something like this:

```
public function ages_12()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->where('age',12);
    $crud->set_table('table_name');
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_view_output($output);
}
```